# Remove nofollow on links on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, spam, external-links

It doesn't make much sense to require that everyone that use information from Stack Overflow link back to it with `nofollow` and then making it impossible to follow the same rule for other sites.

For example, I've just written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299312/how-to-set-default-uuid-ossp-extension-to-all-migration-files-using-rails/37576487#37576487) based on the [Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) that is licensed with [Creative Commons](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#footer), then I'm violating the copyright based on [**your own** understanding](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) on the subject.

So I'm not sure how to prevent spammers to use Stack Overflow to promote websites, but making something that you think is wrong is not the right solution.

### Update

Based on the comment by Brad Larson he quoted:

> To this end, if you find a post that clearly can be trusted whose links are nofollowed, report it. Keep a list. If we can adjust our criteria such that more good links are followed, we'll do so.

But, in the practice, it is not easy to help with that, it is hard to see which links are nofollowed ([some solutions are here][5], but they are not *easy*). It is not clear how to report those links and is also not clear what should be done with the rest of the links.

What I would propose is a simple policy for external links:

1. At the end, there should not be nofollowed links on Stack Overflow, then, the nofollow should be a temporary solution to prevent spam.
2. Nofollowed links should be highlighted to users with some reputation so they easily review those links.
3. There should be only two possible actions on posts with external links, if they are valid links (not spam) they should be accepted, if they are spam they are reported as such.

What do you think about it?

Comment: Do the Ruby on Rails guides specify that they want backlinks with `nofollow` turned off?

Comment: I believe `nofollow` is removed at a certain reputation level. Not quite sure about that though, these things tend to change.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257962/are-the-se-additions-to-the-creative-commons-attribution-requirements-enforceabl - so I think such requirements are quite dubious, and always have been. If you're using a crayon license, you're not using the CC, and in fact you are [misusing the CC trademark](https://creativecommons.org/faq/) by attempting to pass it as that. See "Alterations and additions to the license".

Comment: ["To this end, if you find a post that clearly can be trusted whose links are nofollowed, report it."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209309/what-is-the-threshold-for-removing-rel-nofollow-from-links-in-posts/209398#209398)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Pekka's link to wikipedia still has `rel="nofollow"`, so I don't think that's the case. Same situation for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37280902/563532).

Comment: @Rob see Brad's link, meta sites always use `nofollow`, but you could report the other answer you linked to.

Answer (score 11):

> For example, I've just written an answer based on the Ruby on Rails guides that is licensed with creative commons, then I'm violating the copyright based on your own understanding on the subject.

There doesn't seem to be anything about not using `nofollow` in the core CC license. It's something SO has tacked on on its own content. (Whether it is enforceable or not is a [different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257962/are-the-se-additions-to-the-creative-commons-attribution-requirements-enforceabl).) It doesn't apply to all CC licensed content and it doesn't appear to apply to  the Ruby on Rails guides you mention.

Anyway - when indeed it *is* the case that you're quoting from a resource that has a no-`nofollow` requirement (which at the moment you can't fulfill when linking from SO), then see to it that the material you are using stays inside the [Fair Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) threshold (which allows you to quote, within reason, from *any* material, no matter how it is licensed).

Limiting your use of external resources to a Fair Use-compatible minimum when on Stack Overflow is a great idea anyway: an answer should always be able to stand on its own and not depend *entirely* on an external resource.

Conversely, if you want to quote a SO post somewhere else (like in a programming forum), you also do not need to adhere to neither the CC license, nor SO's linking requirements, as long as your use of the post is within the boundaries of Fair Use.

With that in mind, it's hard to see any hypocrisy here on SO's part. If the site were in the business of scraping and using external resources like the RoR guides *wholesale*, then you could argue that the `nofollow` clause is unfair. But that isn't what SO is doing.

See also: [Fair use FAQ](https://www.teachingcopyright.org/handout/fair-use-faq) at teachingcopyright.org